# How to grab smarty string for php consumption

Tags: php, variables, smarty

I know we should avoid the {php} tag inside any template engine, still, let's assume that it's the only way on this case.

Considering this, I would like to request some help in order to grab smarty string for php consumption.

On this case, I would like to access $video.yt_id inside the srtstr php function.

What am I doing wrong?

How to grab smarty string {$video.yt_id} for php consumption ?

```
{php}
$youtube    = new YouTube( 'I-WANT-THE-YOUTUBE-ID-HERE' );

$meta       = $youtube->get_meta();
$author     = $youtube->get_author();
$comments   = $youtube->get_comments();
{/php}

<p>
Duration: {php} echo sprintf( "%0.2f", $meta['duration'] / 60 ); {/php}mins | 
Rated: {php} echo $meta['rating']; {/php} out of 5 | 
Posted by {php} echo $author['username']; {/php} ( {php} echo $author['age']; {/php} y/o from {php} echo $author['location']; {/php} )
{php} echo nl2br( $meta['description'] ); {/php}
</p>
```

Comment: No, don't assume that. By the way, that's so full of `{php}` tags that I can't believe you are using smarty.

Answer (score 1):

this should  help

```
{php}
    $video = $this->get_template_vars( 'video' );

    $youtube    = new YouTube( $video[ 'yt_id' ] );

    $meta       = $youtube->get_meta();
    $author     = $youtube->get_author();
    $comments   = $youtube->get_comments();

    $this->assign( 'meta', $meta );
    $this->assign( 'author', $author );
    $this->assign( 'comments', $comments );
{/php}

<p>
{assign var="format" value="%0.2f"}
{assign var="meta_duration60" value=$meta.duration/60}
Duration: {$format|sprintf:$duration}mins | 
Rated: {$meta.rating} out of 5 | 
Posted by {$author.username} ( {$author.age} y/o from {$author.location} )
{$meta.description|nl2br}
</p>
```

you can access smarty variables inside `{php}` tags using `$this->get_template_vars( $varname )` and make variable from inside the `{php}` available to the rest of the template with `$this->assign( 'varname', $varname )`

the changes to the output are untested, I hope it'll work